# What's the name of the font used for the title graphic of the video game 'SOMA'?

Tags: font-identification

I'm having quite a bit of trouble identifying which font exactly is being used on the title graphic for the horror videogame *SOMA*. The actual appearance of the font is obscured by the 'glitched' effect that the text uses, and due to this, What Font Is was unable to figure it out due to how it detects characters in the image provided here.

[image: SOMA title graphic]
(Image courtesy of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soma_(video_game)))

**What's the name of the font used here?**

Comment: Looks like a highly modified version of something like Helvetica Neue.  You aren't going to find that same exact font, with all the distortion and stuff around it, you'll have to do that by hand.

Comment: @JohnManly Of course. I was never asking for the font used that included the distortion, just what font was used to make this version of the title text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the curves in the S, it is clearly some version of Helvetica. The O is slightly too circular in the logo, but other than that [Helvetica Neue Heavy](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/neue-helvetica/helvetica-85-heavy/glyphs.html) looks like a plausible starting point.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

I use "HACKED". It is slightly different, but gives interference.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. OP wants to know what was the font used in that image - also this is a 4 years old question with an already accepted answer. Check [answer] and take the [tour] to learn how the site works.